# open street map 504

Tags: openstreetmap, http-status-code-504

Recently I am having problems with the tile servers of OSM, has anyone noticed an increase in the response times or the failures (504) of the petitions to:
 - http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
 - http://tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png

[This is the map view with the loading errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5y1A.png)
[Console showing the 504 errors in the requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH7vG.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenStreetMap often sends Gateway Timeout error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757554/openstreetmap-often-sends-gateway-timeout-error)