# OpenStreetMap often sends Gateway Timeout error

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I am using a leaflet map in program with the following code:

```
<style>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    @import url(//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.2/leaflet.css);
    #map {
        width: 960px;
        height: 500px;
    }
</style>

<body>
   <div id="map"/>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {maxZoom: 20, attribution: osmAttrib});

        var map = L.map('map').setView([37.5, -115], 6).addLayer(osm);

</body>
```

However, I keep seeing some grey square on my maps at random positions and I get the following Leaflet error code in the javascript console:

```
http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/6/8/25.png 504 (Gateway Timeout)
```

Would anyone know what's wrong and how to solve it?

Comment: I've seen several similar reports lately. It's the OSM server returning an error, not leaflet or your code. Suggest following up in an OSM forum.

Comment: Ok I should probably edit my question then (so it shows up on google) and take it to an OSM forum!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A 50x error from the OpenStreetMap tile servers is a problem caused on the OSM side of things, not a problem caused by your use (or misuse) of OSM tiles in your website or application.

Judging by the specific time and date of your question, I'll make a wild assumption and say that you were hitting one of the squid proxy servers <s>during a momentary overload of the network</s> while a system-wide upgrade from squid 2 to squid 3 has been going on for the past few days (note the screenshot below is for the git repo holding the [chef devops recipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chef_(software)) for the OSM servers, and also the fact that *I* can see the status of the OSM servers is awesome).

[image: Screenshot from OSMF's repo for Chef recipes]

Please keep in mind that the OSM tile servers and proxy servers are maintained by a team of (awesome) **volunteer** system administrators and, while they do their best to keep everything up and running, the [OSM Foundation](https://wiki.osmfoundation.org) can *not* make any guarantees about the quality of service.

Read more about this at https://operations.osmfoundation.org/ and specifically at https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/

> Would anyone know what's wrong and *how to solve it*?

In general, temporarily failures of the OSMF services can be solved by:

- Having patience and waiting for the sysadmins to fix things.
- Lurking at the OFTC #OSM-dev IRC channel ([more info here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/IRC)) to know specifically what's wrong and *politely* asking. If you do so, do not be a nuisance to the people there; it will only slow things down.
- Donating money to the OSMF so it can increase its operational capabilities.
- Volunteering to be a part of the [OSMF Operations Working Group](https://wiki.osmfoundation.org/wiki/Operations_Working_Group), or contributing with hardware for mirror servers or the like.

If you do not want to be bound by the limitations of the OSMF, there are a couple common alternatives:

- Use a commercial tile provider (some of the providers are listed [here](https://switch2osm.org/providers/))
- Host your own tiles ([more information here](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/))
- Cache the tiles. Unlike most commercial vendors, OSM allows you to store, proxy, and cache the tiles in pretty much whatever way you want. In fact, anything that will lessen the load on the OSMF servers is encouraged, as long as you take a modicum of care (i.e. do not seed your cache, which would trigger bulk downloads).

Comment: Thanks for the very well documented answer. Well actually I have been having the problem almost constantly for 3 days now, so I am quite unsure it's due to a temporary problem.

Comment: I've been looking at the history of the #osm-dev IRC channel, and it also seems that the squid servers have been upgraded a couple of days ago, and a couple of them (ridgeback and culebre) have been having some issues serving 50x errors to end users; I might be wrong in my analysis of the error. Hanging out on the IRC channel might be a good thing to do.

Comment: Ok thank you again @IvanSanchez will mark your answer as accepted. (I already up-voted it anyway).

Comment: 2019/11 happening again?
https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=68026